# Mysql Trigger - How to trigger on particular row only

Tags: mysql, linux, triggers

I have a hypothetical table, fruit.  It looks like this:

```
Product | Value

Apple     1
Orange    2
```

I am trying to create a trigger that will execute before update that will add 2 to the value only if the new value was for the apple. What would this trigger look like?  Example someone executed

```
UPDATE fruit SET value=2 WHERE product='apple';
```

The new value for apple would be 4.

I tried the trigger below but of course that updates any value with 2

```
BEGIN 
  SET value = new.value+2
END
```

Comment: have you read this? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/trigger-syntax.html
Please let us know what you've tried..

Comment: Mysql is all very new to me, triggering even more so. I have tried SET new.value = new.value+2 which of course updates oranges or apples

Comment: please share the necessary/full code (about the trigger that you've tried - you can see the syntax in the link I gave you before) with us and what error/wrong output you got; so we will know what your problem is.. and others might have more chance in helping you..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use code something like this in your trigger:

```
if new.product = 'Apple' then
    set new.value = new.value + 2;
end if;
```

Comment: @user3567263: then actually you got your answer here..
you have to update the **new** value in your **update data**, so you set the **new.value** like @Bohemian's code..

and you need a conditional statement too.. because you only want this to be applied to `Apple`'s update..

hope this gives you more insight.. and please read more in the documentation.. you can learn a lot more there..